# Simultaneously running many multiple regressions with different formulas at once using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression, lm

I am trying to run many multiple regressions at once with slightly different formulas. I found a good example here: https://rpubs.com/Marcelobn/many_regressions

However, I can't quite get it to run different formulas for each regression... I am looking for help to either fix my updated code or provide an alternative method. Thank you in advance!

I am using R Studio, and have highlighted what I have already tried below (example2).

```
library(pwt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(pander)


example <- pwt7.1

# This works great, and I still want an output like this:
multiple_growth <- example %>% select(country, openc, cg, cgdp) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  nest(-country) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(cgdp ~ openc + cg, data = .)),
         tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidied) 

# BUT: it assumes each of the models for each country are the same
# I want to specify different formulas for each one
example2 <- example

# I have randomly assigned them for the purpose of this example
# In reality I get to this a more methodical way!
formula1 <- paste("cgdp", "~", "openc", "+", "cg", sep = " ")
formula2 <- paste("cgdp", "~", "openc", "+", "cg", "+", "currency", "+", "ppp", sep = " ")
formula3 <- paste("cgdp", "~", "pg", "+", "kg", "+", "openc", sep = " ")


randvar = sample(c(formula1,formula2,formula3), size = nrow(example2), replace = TRUE)
example2$regress = randvar




# Run model again with slight change to lm, and it kind of works
multiple_growth_2 <- example2 %>% select(country, openc, cg, cgdp, currency, ppp, pg, kg, regress) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  nest(-country, -regress) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(as.formula(regress), data = .)), # here is where i have tried to change it
         tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidied) 

# This kind of works but it uses the first formula for ALL of the other countries... Any idea how to fix / an alternate method?
```

A similar output is what I would like, but with the regressions using the correct formula for each and not just the first on in the list for all...

Answer (score 1):

Use `map2` to iterate over formula and dataframe:

```r
multiple_growth_2 <- example2 %>%
    select(country, openc, cg, cgdp, currency, ppp, pg, kg, regress) %>% 
    na.omit() %>%
    nest(-country, -regress) %>% 
    mutate(model = map2(data, regress, ~ lm(as.formula(.y), data = .x)), 
           tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
    unnest(tidied)
```

You should also remove "currency" from `formula2`. You nest on country, so most (if not all) of your dataframes will only contain one currency, but at least two factor levels (i.e. currencies) are required for contrasts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are training your model on the whole data set, you can choose your formulas (or models) as a separate object and add them later with `tidyr::crossing` :

```r
library(pwt, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

example <- as_tibble(pwt7.1)

formulas <- c(
        formula1 =  paste("cgdp", "~", "openc", "+", "cg", sep = " "),
        formula2 =  paste("cgdp", "~", "openc", "+", "cg", "+", "ppp", sep = " "),
        formula3 =  paste("cgdp", "~", "pg", "+", "kg", "+", "openc", sep = " ")
)

multiple_growth_2 <- example %>%
        select(country, openc, cg, cgdp, currency, ppp, pg, kg) %>% 
        na.omit() %>%
        nest(-country) %>%
        tidyr::crossing(. , formulas) %>% 
        mutate(model = pmap(list(x = data, y = formulas), function(x, y) lm( as.formula(y), data = x))
        )

# --- Use broom to

# evaluate models
multiple_growth_2 %>% 
        mutate(model_glance = map(model, glance) ) %>% 
        unnest(model_glance) %>% 
        select(-data, -model)
#> # A tibble: 570 x 13
#>    country formulas r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df
#>    <fct>   <chr>        <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#>  1 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~    0.550         0.527   179.     23.2  2.56e- 7     3
#>  2 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~    0.551         0.514   181.     15.1  1.39e- 6     4
#>  3 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~    0.599         0.567   171.     18.5  1.74e- 7     4
#>  4 Albania cgdp ~ ~    0.519         0.494  1247.     20.5  9.17e- 7     3
#>  5 Albania cgdp ~ ~    0.746         0.726   917.     36.3  4.09e-11     4
#>  6 Albania cgdp ~ ~    0.626         0.596  1114.     20.7  4.93e- 8     4
#>  7 Algeria cgdp ~ ~    0.0754        0.0368 1916.      1.96 1.52e- 1     3
#>  8 Algeria cgdp ~ ~    0.824         0.813   844.     73.5  9.02e-18     4
#>  9 Algeria cgdp ~ ~    0.482         0.449  1449.     14.6  7.58e- 7     4
#> 10 Angola  cgdp ~ ~    0.581         0.559   971.     26.4  6.56e- 8     3
#> # ... with 560 more rows, and 5 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>,
#> #   BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>

# check coefficient
multiple_growth_2 %>%
        mutate(model_tidy = map(model, tidy) ) %>% 
        unnest(model_tidy)
#> # A tibble: 2,089 x 7
#>    country   formulas        term    estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>    <fct>     <chr>           <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ (Inter~   255.       77.7      3.28    2.21e-3
#>  2 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ openc      -5.03      1.09    -4.60    4.63e-5
#>  3 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ cg         70.0      10.3      6.80    4.55e-8
#>  4 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ (Inter~   230.      130.       1.78    8.38e-2
#>  5 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ openc      -4.82      1.40    -3.45    1.41e-3
#>  6 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ cg         72.7      15.3      4.76    2.92e-5
#>  7 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ openc +~ ppp        -1.88      7.79    -0.241   8.11e-1
#>  8 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ pg + kg~ (Inter~   452.      101.       4.46    7.38e-5
#>  9 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ pg + kg~ pg         -6.11      2.40    -2.54    1.53e-2
#> 10 Afghanis~ cgdp ~ pg + kg~ kg         64.2       9.67     6.63    8.76e-8
#> # ... with 2,079 more rows

# check individual prediction
multiple_growth_2 %>%
        mutate(model_augment = map(model, augment) ) %>% 
        unnest(model_augment)
#> # A tibble: 26,820 x 15
#>    country formulas  cgdp openc    cg .fitted .se.fit .resid   .hat .sigma
#>    <fct>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  247.  21.7  5.28    515.    42.5  -267. 0.0562   176.
#>  2 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  241.  27.1  5.73    520.    39.3  -278. 0.0481   175.
#>  3 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  240.  32.9  6.11    517.    36.7  -277. 0.0419   176.
#>  4 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  273.  27.7  5.74    518.    39.1  -245. 0.0476   177.
#>  5 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  324.  28.9  5.36    485.    40.7  -160. 0.0517   180.
#>  6 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  363.  26.9  6.99    609.    36.2  -246. 0.0408   177.
#>  7 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  410.  28.1  6.60    576.    36.3  -167. 0.0409   179.
#>  8 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  441.  26.5  6.97    610.    36.4  -169. 0.0413   179.
#>  9 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  487.  24.7  7.08    626.    37.3  -139. 0.0434   180.
#> 10 Afghan~ cgdp ~ ~  505.  26.4  7.07    617.    36.4  -112. 0.0413   181.
#> # ... with 26,810 more rows, and 5 more variables: .cooksd <dbl>,
#> #   .std.resid <dbl>, ppp <dbl>, pg <dbl>, kg <dbl>
```

Note : I am using `purrr::pmap` for the sake of providing a different answer (`purrr::map2` does the job too !).